# Difference between "should not" and "should avoid"

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference between `should not` and `should avoid` or more generally between `not` and `avoid`
e.g

```
You should not be drinking.
You should avoid drinking.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be much difference between the two. It all depends on the intonation used. Nevertheless,

> You should avoid drinking.

sounds cautionary.

> You should not be drinking.

sounds obligatory.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Should Not may be seen as a command or something that is expected to be followed, because there is a reason to it.
ex: One should not play with fire.

Should avoid is USED more like an advice. In theory, should is used when there is a reason/history to the verb/object of the sentence. So the difference between not and avoid becomes a matter of expression.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a technical manual, there may be a significant difference: one implying an absolute rule, the other providing guidance. For example:

one should not use the camcorder underwater.

one should avoid using the camcorder is a dusty environment.

Answer (score 1):

> You should not be drinking

sounds like an admonition in the present tense. You are drinking now, and you should not be.

> You should avoid drinking

sounds like general advice, not time-specific.

> A piece of friendly advice: *you should not be drinking* [right now], and *you should avoid drinking* [in general].